# Check when a information provided from sql changes in php

Tags: php, sql

I want to get a warning when a date is different like:
[image]

I have a while and wanted to when it reaches to a different date, it warns me

```
$hist=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from history");
while($his=mysqli_fetch_assoc($hist)){

    If(certain_date != last_date){
        echo certain_date;
  }
}
```

Certain date and last date is the ones I wanna get

Comment: Well show us the while loop, and tell us how you want to be warned. Otherwise this question is far too broad to be answered

Comment: Please read [mcve] first.

Comment: Thats not a `while` loop. its just a while statement. Dont be COY, show us all of the loop

Comment: why don't you just use a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Because I still wanted to get the other dates not just one in specific

Comment: Bruno: you dont need to add a SOLVED to your question. That is implied when you accept an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply done like this

```
$hist=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from history");
$last_date = '';

while($his=mysqli_fetch_assoc($hist)){

    If($his['ano'] != $last_date){
        echo $his['ano'];
        $last_date = $his['ano'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't knew it was this simple!

Comment: That'd work. Yet, wouldn't just a simple `WHERE` clause do the trick? Hard to say exactly what they want to pull off here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Something fairly simple I am assuming, like purley processing through all the data and spotting where the date changes. I have to assume once this is coded there is actually more that will go on i.e. reporting more info from the table

Comment: @BrunoMoutinho and Riggs: That's what I was going to pop into a comment up there, but hesitated.